How to start syncing a parachain collator with Kusama relay chain while a parathread of the Kusama Coretime parachain is onboarding
In the "Run Parachain Collator" section of the Polkadot Wiki here to use Agile Coretime with Parachains, it says "While the parachain is onboarding, start syncing the collator using the following command to rapidly sync with the specified relay chain.", and then shows a screenshot of how to do it with the Rococo relay chain.
But in the previous steps I reserved ParaID #3352 on Kusama Coretime, and then registered the parachain state and code for that ParaID.
If I follow the instructions and try to specify Kusama relay chain kusama relay chain as shown below, it gives error error Error: Application(Input("Error opening spec file kusama: No such file or directory (os error 2)"))
export PARA_ID=3352
./target/release/adder-collator \
  --parachain-id=$PARA_ID \
  --chain=kusama \
  --sync fast-unsafe

Question: How do I sync this collator with the relevant relay chain of Kusama Coretime while ParaID #3352 is onboarding or after it has finished onboarding?
Note that in the next step I want to assign the purchased bulk coretime core index #54 that was purchased from Lastic.xyz on the Kusama Coretime system parachain to the registered ParaID 3352 with "Final" finality so that it may be renewed.

I think there is a mistake.
--chain kusama should be passed to the relaychain flags. It should be placed after a --.
Check the README here.

That README is 10 months old and doesn't show how to use the --parachain-id=$PARA_ID option, so I do not believe it has been updated to incorporate Agile Coretime. They only started working on PR #14568 into Substrate for the Agile Coretime Broker pallet 12 months ago.
